# Name of a function with arbitrary outputs?

Tags: functions

Is there a specific name for simple functions like $f: \{0,1,2,3\} \to \{3,1,4,1\}$? With arbitrary outputs. Or they are just called discrete functions?

Comment: Define "arbitrary outputs."

Comment: Like a value f(3) = 22 or f(4) = -99. An unpredictable value.

Comment: The name maybe "Random Function".

Comment: Usually the notation you're using has two *sets* to the left and right of the arrow. Your expression on the right has a repeated element, making it seem like a multiset.

Comment: Perhaps you call them functions. I think all functions have arbitrary outputs.